# Unknown error using the c++ eigen library

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

I am a graduate student at Florida State University studying financial mathematics. I am still a bit of a novice with C++ but I am trying to implement the Longstaff-Schwartz method for pricing of American options. Although, the algorithm in the journal is a bit daunting thus I am trying to convert the code that was written in Matlab and change it into C++. Essentially I am using the Matlab code as a guide.

I was referred by some stackexchange users to use the Eigen library which contains a good matrix class. Unfortunately the website [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Download) does not show me how to make my own function from the class. What I am stuck on is making a C++ function for the function in Matlab that does this:

Say `t = 0:1/2:1` then in Matlab the output will be `t = 0  0.500  1`

So using the Eigen class I created a function called range to achieve the latter above. The function looks like this:

```
MatrixXd range(double min, double max, double N){
     MatrixXd m(N,1);
     double delta = (max-min)/N;
     for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
             m(i,j) = min + i*delta;
         }
     }
    return m;
}
```

I do not have any errors on my IDE (Ecclipse) but when I run my code and test this function I get this error message:

```
c:\mingw\include\c++\6.2.0\eigen\src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:736:7: 

error: static assertion failed:



FLOATING_POINT_ARGUMENT_PASSED__INTEGER_WAS_EXPECTED
```

I am not sure what is wrong. Any suggestions on achieving what I am trying to do or any suggestions at all are greatly appreciated.

Taking the suggestion by Martijn Courteaux, I changed $N$ into an int now but I now receive a new error that I do not understand:

```
c:\mingw\include\c++\6.2.0\eigen\src/Core/Matrix.h:350:7: error: static

assertion failed: THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE

       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_SPECIFIC_SIZE(Matrix, 3)
```

For sake of completeness I will post my whole code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;


double LaguerreExplicit(int R, double x); // Generates the (weighted) laguerre value
double payoff_Call(double S, double K); // Pay off of a call option
double generateGaussianNoise(double mu, double sigma); // Generates Normally distributed random numbers
double LSM(int T, double r, double sigma, double K, double S0, int N, int M, int R);
// T        Expiration time
// r        Riskless interest rate
// sigma    Volatility
// K        Strike price
// S0       Initial asset price
// N        Number of time steps
// M        Number of paths
// R        Number of basis functions

MatrixXd range(double min, double max, int N);

int main(){

    MatrixXd range(0, 1, 2);



}


double payoff_Call(double S, double K){
    double payoff;
    if((S - K) > 0)
    {
        payoff = S - K;
    }else
    {
        payoff = 0.0;
    }
    return payoff;
}

double LaguerreExplicit(int R, double x){
    double value;
    if(R==0)
    {
        value = 1;
    }
    else if(R==1)
    {
        value = 0.5*(pow(x,2) - 4.0*x + 2);
    }
    else if(R==3)
    {
        value = (1.0/6.0)*(-1*pow(x,3) + 9*pow(x,2) - 18*x + 6);
    }
    else if(R==4)
    {
        value = (1.0/24.0)*(pow(x,4) - 16*pow(x,3) + 72*pow(x,2) - 96*x + 24);
    }
    else if(R==5)
    {
        value = (1.0/120.0)*(-1*pow(x,5) + 25*pow(x,4) - 200*pow(x,3) + 600*pow(x,2) - 600*x + 120);
    }
    else if (R==6)
    {
        value = (1.0/720.0)*(pow(x,6) - 36*pow(x,5) + 450*pow(x,4) - 2400*pow(x,3) + 5400*pow(x,2) - 4320*x + 720);
    }
    else{
        cout << "Error!, R is out of range" << endl;
        value  = 0;
    }
    value = exp(-0.5*x)*value; // Weighted used in Longstaff-Scwartz
    return value;
}

double generateGaussianNoise(double mu, double sigma)
{
    const double epsilon = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    const double two_pi = 2.0*M_PI;

    static double z0, z1;
    static bool generate;
    generate = !generate;

    if (!generate)
       return z1 * sigma + mu;

    double u1, u2;
    do
     {
       u1 = rand() * (1.0 / RAND_MAX);
       u2 = rand() * (1.0 / RAND_MAX);
     }
    while ( u1 <= epsilon );

    z0 = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u1)) * cos(two_pi * u2);
    z1 = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u1)) * sin(two_pi * u2);
    return z0 * sigma + mu;
}

MatrixXd range(double min, double max, int N){
     MatrixXd m(N,1);
     double delta = (max-min)/N;
     for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
             m(i,j) = min + i*delta;
         }
     }
    return m;
}

double LSM(int T, double r, double sigma, double K, double S0, int N, int M, int R){
    double dt = T/N;
    MatrixXd m(T,1);

    return 0;

}
```

Here is the corrected function code that I fixed:

```
VectorXd range(double min, double max, int N){
    VectorXd m(N + 1);
     double delta = (max-min)/N;
     for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
             m(i) = min + i*delta;
     }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: I think what you want is just `Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(N+1, min, max)` http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aaef589c1dbd7fad93f97bd3fa1b1e768

Comment: Also, if you are used to Matlab programming, this [AsciiQuickReference](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt) will likely be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mistake is here:

```
MatrixXd range(double min, double max, double N){
     MatrixXd m(N,1);
```

`N` is a double. The arguments of `MatrixXd::MatrixXd(int, int)` are `int`.

You presumably want to make `N` an `int`.

---

In regard to your edit:

Second mistake is here:

```
MatrixXd range(0, 1, 2);
```

in the `main()` function. Not sure what you are trying to do here, but that constructor is not valid. **EDIT:** Ah I believe I have an idea. You are trying to call your function named `range`. Do this like this:

```
MatrixXd result = range(0.0, 1.0, 2);
```

Comment: I see, the reason I made it a double was because I am going to be dividing a double by a double. I thought there would be an error if I divided a double and then an int?

Comment: No, that's fine. The int gets promoted to a double before the division. All floating point +*-/ integral type operations work that way.

Comment: Also, when I change N into an int variable I get this error: c:\mingw\include\c++\6.2.0\eigen\src/Core/Matrix.h:350:7: error: static assertion failed: THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE

Comment: It looks like you are trying to construct a MatrixXd with three doubles as constructor arguments. You are probably doing this somewhere else (code not shown in your question).

Comment: I see, well what I am trying to do is just test the function I made. Is that not how you call it in main?

Comment: No that is indeed not the way. What you were doing is creating an object on the stack of type MatrixXd, called "range", using the `MatrixXd(double, double, double)` constructor, which is explicitly made unavailable for MatrixXd using that compile-time static assertion. I updated my answer again.

Comment: right, I orginally had it set to t = range(0,1,2) but it still did not work. Anyways, I copied how you declared it in main but my ecclipse IDE said: This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: Attach a debugger to it (like gdb or lldb, I don't know if eclipse can do this for you easily), to see where it fails. I can't help you any further here.

Comment: However, I found another bug: Your matrix is Nx1 in size. Yet you are looping over it as if it is an NxN matrix. (In the range function, you access it by `m(i, j)`, which assumes an NxN matrix.)

Comment: It says it fails at the declaration  MatrixXd t = range(0.0, 1.0, 2); in the main function

Comment: I see, I thought that is what I needed to do since MatrixXd m(N,1) will simply make m into a column vector

Comment: Just so you know I fixed it by changing MatrixXd into just VectorXd (didn't know they had that in Eigen library) thank you for your time